# Search only in files that match a pattern with ack

Tags: ack

Can ack search only through files that match a specific 'glob' pattern (eg: search for foo in all files named "bar*.c"). The command

```
ack foo "bar*.c"
```

only works in the current directory.

Note: I know it's possible with find -exec:

```
find . -name "bar*.c" -type f -exec ack foo {} +
```

But I would like a small and simple ack command, because find doesn't skip version control directories.

Comment: I don't understand, what's wrong with using `find  . -name "bar*.c" -exec ack foo {}  \;`? There's nothing special about `grep`, you can use _any_ command with find's `-exec`.

Comment: @terdon find also searches through version control directories and I don't want that.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and explain the limitations you need to work around.

Comment: i find it [better to use ripgrep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30138655/274502)

Answer (score 37):

#### Searching directories

Based on the synopsis shown in the man page I would say yes it can process a directory, but looking at the switches it cannot look for just a file based on a pattern. For that you'll have to enlist `find`. The command `ack` does include the option `--files-from=FILE` so that it can be fed a list of files from `find`.

*synopsis*

```
       ack [options] PATTERN [FILE...]
       ack -f [options] [DIRECTORY...]
```

*usage*

```
   --files-from=FILE
       The list of files to be searched is specified in FILE.  The list of
       files are separated by newlines.  If FILE is "-", the list is
       loaded from standard input.
```

There is the `--ignore-file=` option which may give you what you want but seems a bit of a pain to actually use.

```
   --ignore-file=FILTERTYPE:FILTERARGS
       Ignore files matching FILTERTYPE:FILTERARGS.  The filters are
       specified identically to file type filters as seen in "Defining
       your own types".
```

#### Searching specific types of files

The only other way I can conceive of doing just this via `ack` is to use its `--type` switch:

```
   --type=[no]TYPE
       Specify the types of files to include or exclude from a search.
       TYPE is a filetype, like perl or xml.  --type=perl can also be
       specified as --perl, and --type=noperl can be done as --noperl.

       If a file is of both type "foo" and "bar", specifying --foo and
       --nobar will exclude the file, because an exclusion takes
       precedence over an inclusion.
```

To see what types are available:

```
$ ack --help-types | grep -E "perl|cpp"
```

format.  For example, both --type=perl and --perl work.
    --[no]cpp          .cpp .cc .cxx .m .hpp .hh .h .hxx
    --[no]objcpp       .mm .h
    --[no]perl         .pl .pm .pod .t .psgi; first line matches /^#!.*\bperl/
    --[no]perltest     .t

#### Examples

Find all the Perl files, based on both the filename (*.pm, *.pl, *.t and *.pod) and the shebang line.

```
$ ack -f --type perl 
examples/iwatch/iwatch/iwatch
examples/nytprof_perl/bad.pl
```

Find all the C++ files:

```
$ ack -f --type=cpp
Shared/Scanner.h
Shared/Sorter.h
Shared/DicomHelper.cpp
Shared/DicomDeviationWriter.h
```

#### Searching for foo in bar*.c

So then how can you accomplish what you want? Well you'll have to likely use `find` to do this:

```
$ find adir -iname "bar*.c" | ack --files-from=- foo
adir/bar1.c
1:foo
2:foo

adir/dir1/bar1.c
1:foo
2:foo
```

You can also use `ack`'s ability to search for files that match a given pattern in their filenames (using `-g <pattern>`), and then pass this list to a second invocation of `ack` using `-x` or `--files-from=-`..

Using `-x`:

```
$ ack -g '\bbar.*.c$' | ack -x foo
bar1.c
1:foo
2:foo

dir1/bar1.c
1:foo
2:foo
```

Using `-files-from=-`:

```
$ ack -g '\bbar.*.c$' | ack --files-from=- foo
bar1.c
1:foo
2:foo

dir1/bar1.c
1:foo
2:foo
```

In either case we're matching the filenames that you want using this regex:

```
\bbar.*.c$
```

This matches files whose name is `bar.*c` and end after the `.c` using the end of line anchor, `$`. We also look to make sure that the names have a boundary character using `\b`. This will fail for files that contain boundary characters such as `$bar.c` or `%bar.c` for example.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question (search for foo in all files named "bar*.c")

Comment: @compie - it does in the sense I'm showing you how to get a slice of the files you want. To search for `cpp` files `ack --type=cpp <string>`. See `ack`'s man page for more on all this though. But what I'm basically telling you is that you cannot search using `ack` the way that you want.

Comment: so it does answer in the sense that it shows `ack` cannot do what was asked.

Comment: @xealits - this part answers it: **Searching for foo in bar*.c** `find adir -iname "bar*.c" | ack --files-from=- foo`. Or, if you just want one file: `echo "barBaz.c" | ack --files-from=- foo`

Comment: tldr; ```ack -g '\bbar.*.c$' | ack -x foo```

Answer (score 18):

It's easy if the file type is known, and ack knows a lot of file types. So if, for example, you want to only search in C files, than you can do:

```
ack --cc 'string'
```

But if it's not one of the known extensions, you need to define your own type. This should work:

```
ack --type-set barc:match:/bar.+\.c/ --barc 'string'
```

Note that you need both --type-set and --barc.

(Thanks to Andy, who also helped with this on the mailing list.)

Comment: Ok that works but using find and 'ack -x' is simpler. I think I will stick with that.

Comment: Adding a link to the docs here would be helpful. `man ack` doesn't really help and doesn't have `cc` when I search that.

Comment: ack --help=types  There's everthing I can think of there. I mostly use it for Python and Ada.

Comment: somehow `ack --help=types` does not work on mac's version v3.3.1 (works on linux' version 2.26). A [handy cheatsheet](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Ack.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index) might help: `--[no]cmake --[no]rake --[no]cpp --[no]python` and many more are there.

Answer (score 10):

This would seem to be the fastest and safest:

```
find . -name '*.c' | ack -x 'some string'
```

*-x* *Read the list of files to search from STDIN.*

However, if the file is likely to be in your `locate` database, this would be even quicker:

```
locate --basename '*.c' | ack -x 'some thing'
```

Locate can also accept old-school regular expressions, a little painful, but if you're looking for `c` files, it might be required.
*e.g.*

```
locate --basename --regex '\.\(c\|cpp\|h\|hpp\|cc\)$' |
    ack -x 'some thing'
```

*That just translates to: "search all filename that end in c, cpp, h, hpp or cc."*

For @nyxee who raised a very good question, the only answer I can see is to add another pipe:

```
locate --basename --regex '\.\(c\|cpp\|h\|hpp\|cc\)$' |
    grep -v '/\.'                                     |
    ack -x 'some thing'
```

*That will skip any directory or subdirectory that starts with a `.`*

Comment: how do we exclude hidden directories with the extension. For example, we have very very many directories named ``.gradle`` while searching for gradle files.

Comment: Usw ```locate --basename --regexp '.+\.\(c\|cpp\|h\|hpp\|cc\)$' |
    ack -x 'some thing' ``` TO EXCLUDE DIRECTORIES THAT MAY HAVE NAMES LIKE `.CPP` nad `.HPP`.  I have only added the `.+' operator so that a filename must exist before the extension which is the usual pravtice.

Comment: thanks best answer for all files types! why? because next time I need it can remember it ;)

Comment: @nyxee valid question, i have updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

"What's new in ack 2?" http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.0/

> with ack 2.0, you can use the new -x to pipe filenames from one
>   invocation of ack into another.

```
ack2 -g -i filepattern | ack2 -x -w searchpattern
```

Only I can't get it to work:

```
% ack -g "*bar*.c"
Invalid regex '*bar*.c':
Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE bar*.c/ at ack line 314.
```

Thus it seems -g needs a regex, while I want a 'glob' style option...

Comment: Yes, `-g` takes a regex, not a glob.  You could write your regex as `.*bar.*\.c$`.

Comment: @AndyLester Thanks for confirming. Do you like the idea of a 'glob' option for ack?

Answer (score 4):

@chim 's answer is the best, but its written as a comment so I'm reposting as a formal answer...

```
ack -g '\bbar.*.c$' | ack -x foo
```

I like the fact that your can regex the path...

Comment: best answer for ease of use.

Answer (score 2):

Ack doesn't support glob style file selection. Since I really miss this I created a small shell script **ackg**:

```
#!/bin/sh
# 'glob' support for ack
find -name "$2" -type f -exec ack "$1" {} +
```

Now you can use the command:

```
ackg foo "bar*.c"
```

But note: this will unfortunately also search in version control dirs (eg: .git).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the `-G` option to [ag, the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) (an enhanced clone of ack-grep).

```
$ echo foo > bar_wanted.c
$ echo foo > unwanted.c
$ ag -G "bar.*\.c" foo
bar_wanted.c
1:foo
```

Notes:

- [`ag` uses PCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190334/ag-silver-searcher-what-are-the-rules-for-patterns) regular expression syntax, so the regexp must be `bar.*\.c` instead of `bar*.c`.
- The `-G` option needs to precede the search term, as anything after that is interpreted as a filename.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want only a certain pattern, or do you just want C source files?

If you want all C files, use

```
ack --cc foo
```

If you want all C files and NOT C header files use

```
ack --cc --no-hh foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Using zsh you can do:

```
ls **/a*.txt | ack --files-from=- something
```

Comment: Note that this will break if your file names contain spaces. [It is very rarely a good idea to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).